# how to add data to list of dictionaries in Django

Tags: django

I want to add data to list of dictionaries

```
  a =[100, 200, 300] 
  b =['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']
  c=[]

  for val in a:
      c.append({'price':val}) 
  for val in b:
      c.append({'fruit':val}) 

 print(c)
```

result should be like this:
[
{'price':100, 'fruit':'apple'}, {'price':200, 'fruit':'orange'}, {'price':300, 'fruit':'grapes'}

Answer (score 2):

You can work with list comprehension:

```
a = [100, 200, 300] 
b = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']
c = [{'price': p, 'fruit': f} for p, f in zip(a, b)]
```